# .NET application using too much ram

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on a .net application with VS in C#. I use a bunch of DataGridView's, and when the application uses about 8 of them with about 6 columns and 2000 rows each, the memory used, according to the task manager is about 1.5g. Is that how is supposed to be or could I be doing something wrong?

Comment: An interresting question about memory management in general http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175707/why-does-the-memory-usage-of-a-net-application-seem-to-drop-when-it-is-minimized

Comment: What makes your think the culprit is the `DataGridView` or the number of rows in each? By the way, how much data is in each row?

Comment: I just found what is causing the problem. See my new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758357/why-is-this-code-consuming-more-and-more-ram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a memory profiler to see where the memory has gone.

There are several:

- One as part of the performance tools which are in the higher levels of VS
- SciTech - http://memprofiler.com/
- JetBrains - http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

You can probably start with an evaluation version to see if you get on with either of the last two.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're storing a lot of data (16K rows, what's the data size of each row?), I wouldn't wonder. You could use the virtual mode, that saves a lot of memory.

Also, have a look at the very good ObjectListView (opensource on sourceforge).

Comment: of course, but we don't know the size of his data. also, in the task manager he can't see the memory used by only the datagrids, he sees the total memory used by the whole application. to test he could create an empty app with only the datagrids.