# Why is this code consuming more and more ram?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool AfterDocumentCompleted = false;
    int steps = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(DocCompletedHandlerCopy);
        webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    }

    private void DocCompletedHandlerCopy(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete && e.Url == webBrowser1.Url)
        {
            AfterDocumentCompleted = true;
        }
    }

    private void NavigateAndWait(string urlString)
    {
        AfterDocumentCompleted = false;
        webBrowser1.Navigate(urlString);
        while (AfterDocumentCompleted == false) Application.DoEvents();

        steps += 1;
        label1.Text = string.Format("{0:00000} / {1}MB", steps, Environment.WorkingSet / (1024 * 1024));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            NavigateAndWait("http://www.crucial.com/");
            NavigateAndWait("http://www.google.com/");
            NavigateAndWait("http://www.microsoft.com/");
            NavigateAndWait("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
            NavigateAndWait("http://www.yahoo.com/");
        }
    }
}
```

When I click Button1 (so it calls `button1_Click`) and wait for about 1 hr, the ram consumed according to Task Manager and `label1` is about 1000MB (is about 20MB as soon as I click it and the rate of grow is somewhat linear). Is the WebBrowser some kind of alpha version of a browser that is not supposed to be used at all by anyone, or am I doing something wrong. If you wonder why in the world do I want to navigate for ever to those pages, this is just the isolation of a problem I was having (see my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749381/net-application-using-too-much-ram)).

**Edit:** About a week ago I installed and uninstalled IE9 beta. I think that might have originated the problem. Just tested it on a Windows Vista IE8 and it didn't grow any bigger than 80-90MB. I'll just reinstall Windows and I hope I don't need to downgrade to Windows Vista.

**Edit2:** I finally found the cause of the problem. It was not IE9 beta. It was the fact that I set IE not to show any pictures. I thought not showing pictures would make navigation faster and lighter, but apparently it activated some bug and the memory consumed started growing like crazy. Still, with pictures the memory grows but a lot slower.

Comment: This is not a real answer but **all** browsers traditionally leak memory left, right and center. This is becoming better with every new generation but even modern browsers still do this. You may be out of luck, especially if the sites load Flash content or other plugins.

Comment: Which Windows version are you on? Task Manager might not show the relevant memory usage (private bytes) on XP or older version. You'd better check this with Process Explorer. Are you really certain that memory will continue to increase for ever?

Comment: In addition to @Konrad Rudolph's remark, memory leaks of IE are even [documented](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830555), though some have been [fixed in IE8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361842%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: is "webBrowser1" static?  If so, each time FormLoad is created, you'll be adding another event to webBrowser - that could result in a memory leak as the old attached events will never be released.

Comment: @Paul  He's in an endless loop so I doubt he's getting around to invoking multiple forms :)

Comment: @colithium, @Paul Hadfield: In the sample code above the `DocumentCompleted` event is only attached once when the form is initialized so this is clearly not the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> and wait for about 10 minutes, the ram consumed according to Task Manager is about 200MB

- 200 MB is not a lot
- TaskManager is not suitable for measuring memory use

The WebBrowser you use through the control is IE. It will consume quite a bit of memory, mostly  to cache content. But you don't really have a problem with memory.

### Additional:

I ran your App and changed only this method (add Label1) :

```
    int counter = 0;

    private void NavigateAndWait(string urlString)
    {
        AfterDocumentCompleted = false;
        webBrowser1.Navigate(urlString);
        while (AfterDocumentCompleted == false) Application.DoEvents();

        counter += 1;
        label1.Text = string.Format("{0:000} {1}", counter, 
           Environment.WorkingSet/ (1024*1024));
    }
```

When I let it run for a while Memory stabilizes at a 75-85 MB range.

In a comment you mention 1.6 GB, that is a problem. But that was not with this code. So you have a start:  look for the differences.

### Edit 2

**Upgrade your version of IE**. I am running this with Vista/32 and IE8 and the WorkingSet won't go over 90MB. (600 pages)

Comment: Do I really have to wait until it reaches 1g? Actually, it already reached 1.6g on the real version of the program. Then my mouse kinda stopped working so I just stopped it. Is the mouse not working and getting Out Of Memory exceptions suitable enough for measuring memory use?

Comment: @jsoldi: What is the real application doing? Knowing that we might come up with a suitable workaround. Checking web pages using the browser control in a tight loop like this seems not like something you would do in a real application as long as you are sane.

Comment: It's a web scraper. Gets information from web pages. You would probably tell me to use a `WebClient` and an HTML parser, but I need to fill forms with JavaScript and stuff like that. I know I can still use a `WebClient` but it would be just way more complicated.

Comment: I'm trying your code. I'll let it run for longer and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Tried it. It reaches 1g after about 1 hr and about 2500 steps. My original application didn't grow any faster that this, so the problem is right here. I'm thinking the problem is with a leak in IE as 0xA3 suggested. I'm using IE 7 and windows vista, .net 4.0. I'll try disposing the WebBrowser and using a new one every time, see what happens.

Comment: Alright. The disposing _might_ help, but since it is largely unmanaged code it is not guaranteed. And please add those details to the question.

Comment: Oh, sorry I meant IE8. My bad. Wonder if it has something to do with installing IE9 beta (that I already uninstalled, for sure). I'm not sure if I had this problem before that. Might need to reinstall Windows.

Comment: Did you actually tried it with the same web pages as I did? I just installed Windows Vista 64 and this are a few steps/MB's over time: 103/111, 343/167, 860/304. About 2.5 steps per MB, which is about the same I was getting before (2500 steps/1g). Please let me know about the web pages you used. Thanks.

Comment: I used your table. Unaltered.

Answer (score 4):

> or am I doing something wrong

Well, this is not going to be a good idea:

```
while (AfterDocumentCompleted == false) Application.DoEvents();
```

You're introducing reentrancy *and* a tight loop in the high priority UI thread. I don't know to what extent that will hamper the garbage collector, but I wouldn't be surprised if it did. Basically you're abusing the UI thread, which is bound to cause oddities. (As Henk says, 200MB in 10 minutes isn't exactly a runaway resource leak anyway.)

This just isn't a good idea. "Isolating" a problem by adding code like this isn't going to help.

You already have a `DocumentCompleted` handler... why not use *that* to navigate to the next page, instead of this tight loop?

Comment: Jon, DoEvents has its problems but how would this block Invoked actions?

Comment: @Timwi: All kinds of odd things may happen when you put the system into a crazy situation like this though.

Comment: Try changing it to only load the next page AFTER DocCompletedHandlerCopy gets called.  Just see what happens

Comment: @colithium: Yes, I was just thinking that myself :)

Comment: Can you suggest another way of making a function `NavigateAndWait`? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @jsoldi: I wouldn't make it wait at all. I'd use the UI thread reactively, which is what it's been designed for. If you want to loop through, navigating with the browser constantly, then navigate in the DocumentCompleted event but don't loop waiting until it's finished.

Comment: Yea maybe I should change tons of code to make it that way but would that fix the memory problem?

Comment: No, it won't. You don't really have a memory problem.

Comment: @colithium: Seems to me that it IS navigating after `DocCompletedHandlerCopy` returns. This is not multi thread. `NavigateAndWait` calls `DoEvents` and `DoEvents` calls `DocCompletedHandlerCopy` so `NavigateAndWait` doesn't return until `DocCompletedHandlerCopy` have returned.

Comment: @jsoldi From the docs: "Navigate asynchronously to the document at the specified Uri."  This comment thread is getting a bit out of hand haha

Comment: @jsoldi: But there's no need to have a loop. Just navigate *in the event handler*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why it would be unclear why you are using lots of memory; you are reloading web pages over and over again endlessly. Right now my browser is using 140megs of memory, and I'm not reloading pages constantly.